# C++. Как подключить библиотеку arduino к с++ проекту?

Tags: c++, arduino

Мне не нужна связка visual studio + arduino, мне нужно библиотеку для arduino включить в с++ проект, но при этом чтобы не было связки с устройством arduino, чтобы все делалось на эмуляторе arduino или на самом пк.

Comment: Также как любую другую библиотеку для с++. Что именно у вас вызвало проблему?

Comment: я думал что без контроллера я не смогу программировать на с++ используя arduino библиотеки

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего в Arduino IDE создать проект, включив в него нужные библиотеки. Затем отправить проект на компиляцию, и после завершения (успешного или нет - разницы нет) зайти в папку %TEMP.

Отыскать там папку своего проекта и скопировать её оттуда. Все используемые с проекте файле будут в этой папке.